# Can I use this rf module with HT12E and HT12D?

Tags: rf, encoder, decoder, 433mhz

I have recently made RC car using HT12E and HT12D connected to a cheap ASK RF module of 433 MHz frequency,but it's range is not good only a few meters and also so prone to electrical noise generated from DC motors,I have tried every solution like covering motor with metal chasis which is connected to ground and low pass filter....but nothing works so finally decided to change frequency,found [this](http://robokits.co.in/shop/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=7&products_id=414)
but unlike normal module,it has 6 pins,I know it's transreceiver so I will buy two pcs but how to use them with HT12E and HT12D,what are PROG and CTS pins and how to use them?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [datasheet](http://www.robokits.co.in/datasheets/WIR-1186_RobokitsIndia.pdf) that module has an async UART interface so it won't be compatible with the HT12E and HT12D. Those are designed to interface with "dumb" RF modules that have a simple data input and output that don't implement any higher level protocols.

I'd suggest attempting to debug your existing solution further or try some alternative transmitter / receiver modules. In my experience the 433MHz modules are normally good for around 20-50 meters at least if the power supply is clean and you have a relatively decent antenna.

Maybe just as a test you could try powering the HT12D / receiver (I assume that's on the motor side?) from a seperate power supply like a battery and see how that goes. I'm guessing if your range is that low with those modules unless they have a defect you may have the same problem with different modules / frequencies.

Comment: Thanks PeterJ for your answer,all that's tempting me to use this module is because of it's range 2 km along with it's low cost,could you please suggest me a nice website to learn about UART and also how can I make my rc car run by using this module(UART communication,no matter even if I have to change my hardware).

Comment: @pra, you'd need to use a microcontroller to realistically use that module, maybe take a look at an Arduino that's probably the simplest way. But looking at the module specs that range is really optimistic - it says 1km typical when the antenna is 10m above ground and line of sight. Under those circumstances I'd expect you could get hundreds of meters with your current module, I really think you have some other problems.

Comment: Thanks again PeterJ,I will stick with my present module,mine frequency is 433 so is 35 cm length wire enoug as antenna?

Comment: ok PeterJ,I will use my present module what should be it's antenna wire length?35 cm?

Comment: @pra, that's about a half wavelength so should be good.